# D3(SVG) browser support

Tags: svg, cross-browser, d3.js

According to caniuse 
http://caniuse.com/#search=svg

there is full support for SVG except for IE 7,8, but when I view in Chrome and Firefox, many examples don't work

For example both azimuthal and albers in the examples found here
https://github.com/mbostock/d3/tree/master/examples

Both work fine in Safari

My browser versions

Chrome
Version 21.0.1180.82

Firefox
14.0.1

Anyone care to comment as to why these examples aren't working?

Comment: In what way do they not work? The azimuthal example seems to display a globe that you can zoom in and out of when I display it in Firefox.

Comment: Are you viewing these examples locally? if so you must have a local web server - see the bottom of https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki

Answer (score 2):

As @Josh commented, the most likely reason is that you are viewing these examples out of your local file system, rather than using a local web server as described on [the Wiki](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki).

> When running the examples locally, note that your browser may enforce strict permissions for reading files out of the local file system. Some examples use AJAX which works differently via HTTP instead of local files. **To view the examples locally, you must have a local web server.** Any web server will work; for example you can run Python's built-in server:
>
> ```
> python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8888 &
> ```
>
> Once this is running, go to `http://localhost:8888/examples/`.